# Stone-look surface via painting?

Tags: filament, post-processing, filament-quality

Has anyone tried painting a PLA (or other) print with stone-look spray paints? In particular, how does the result look compared to printing with stone-fill filaments? It looks a lot cheaper, but will it look inferior?

One such paint: http://www.krylon.com/press-room/press-releases/2013/04/add-a-touch-of-nature-to-your-next-project-with-new-natural-stone-textured-finish/?

One such filament: https://www.matterhackers.com/store/3d-printer-filament?t=LAYBRICK

Comment: Walter Hsiao has tried putting prints into a tumbler with ceramic media. http://thrinter.com/vibratory-tumbler-ceramic/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's totally possible to achieve but the result vastly **depends** on your painting skills and your spray paint quality.

Your can look at [this page](http://www.instructables.com/id/3D-Printed-Stone-Head/?ALLSTEPS) for a concrete example.

How it compares to stone filament is fairly subjective though. Painting a 3D print usually breaks down in 3 steps :

- **Smoothing out the lines.** 
  *Achieved by either sanding the print or using acetone*
- **Apply coating**.
  *Ensures a better adhesion for the paint*
- **Apply spray paint**

If any of these steps are neglected, the final result won't look as good as using stone filament. However, if the quality of you stone filament is really bad, painting will offer a better result.